# How to access script (source) of custom tool stored in tbx?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-script-tool

I have few custom toolboxes, with script tools.
I can access individual toolbar by:

```
ToolBar=arcpy.ImportToolbox(toolbar_path)
```

I can access each tool by iterating through

```
ToolBar.__all__
```

I’d like to search/find key word inside tool’s Python script.

How can I access it?

Comment: Is this a Python Toolbox tool in a *.pyt?

Comment: No. It is 'old' custom toolbox

Comment: That makes it a Python Script tool in a standard toolbox (*.tbx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **getsourceline function** from the [inspect module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) is what you would use to access a script tool's code programmatically, which you can then search. This works for script tools in .pyt toolboxes but not for those in a .tbx.

**EDIT**

I found [this](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=83585412edd04ae48bdffea3e1f7b2e7) tool which allows you to convert  **.tbx** script tools to **.pyt**.

```
import tbxtopyt  #from the package linked above
tool_source_code = tbxtopyt.PYTToolbox(r'path_to_tbx').python_code  #returns string
```

You can then search this string to find what you need.